# ItemsSource data change invokes recreation of DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I have a DataForm where I have specified a DataTemplate for ItemTemplate. ItemsSource is bound to a List property of ViewModel. Wherenever List property changes, DataForm's ItemsSource is updated through notify property change mechanism.

So far, so good. Problem: whenever List property data changes, template is also recreated. I know this because I have a custom control inside a template, so I see that a constructor is fired twice. First time during InitializeComponent call, and second time when List is populated with data from the service.

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: What is your real question? Are you concerned about performance? It is hard to give you a real answer since this doesn't seem like a real question.

Comment: The question is: is it expected behaivor for a particular control to recreate its whole template when a ItemsSource property is changed? Or it is a bug with control? Logic says it should just reload the data.

Comment: If the whole List is changed then there are new items in it. The `ItemsControl` does not compare old items to new ones, it just creates a "new" data template for the new item. If that is causing performance issues, you can iterate the items in the List and update the values that have changed. This way the items will not be new and will not cause re-creation of the data template.

Comment: I am not asking this because I have a performance problem, I was just being curious if that is a default behavior for each templated control, or not. If you say that it is, then make an answer to this question, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final conclusion is that template is recreated whenever ItemsSource is assigned a new List